# cannot ssh from phone to laptop, but can ssh from laptop to phone

Tags: ssh, networking, kali-linux

I have kali Nethunter 3.0 installed on my Nexus 6p device running android oreo, and i have latest version of kali directly installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad T460. I have two seperate  networks for mobile and laptop, I can ssh easily from my laptop to my nethunter device, but I cannot ssh from my kali nethunter to my laptop, even after allowing root login to yes. The only way I can ssh from nethunter to laptop is when both devices are on same network.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there an SSH server running on the laptop? What is the error message?

Comment: It has nothing to do with root: root permissions don't extend across the network. (disable it now). Also stop using kali: it is not for noobs. It is hard to use, powerful, and if you use it wrong, it will take your leg off. Much like an adze.

Comment: am on a home network, i have been using kali since 2012 didn't have any issue until now. using kali not for illegal stuff but for personal work. am  not a noob

Comment: Then how about answering my comment?

Answer (score 0):

Since it works when both devices are on the same network then it must be the router blocking the traffic. check the firewall on your router to see if it's blocking port 22 from your phone network to the laptop network.